# IAP in hybrid app (cordova) - iTunes receipt contains only the first transaction

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins

Here's the thing, for couple days now i am trying to figure out IAP
(apples ios in app purchases) in a hybdrid app.

Everything seems to be working, transactions are triggering end etc...
but when it comes to server side receipt validation the weird begins.

As I mentioned, in the app itself new transaction is made with new unique id.
But when i send **receipt** to the server and my server is asking apple for its validation the info apple is returning **contains only the first transaction that was made**, no indication of the current transaction or any other that was done after the first one.

Anybody experienced something like that?

Additional info:

1. All happens in the sandbox (can it be only the sandbox thing? and in prod it might magically start working?)
2. In the app itself when i ask for receipt, so i can later send it to my server, the receipt is always the same.  From what i have read that is correct since ios7
3. I am using this plugin: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase
4. Auto finishing of the transactions is off (cordova plugin option)
5. Server side lib that i use for receipt validation: https://github.com/chrismaddern/iOS-Receipt-Validator-PHP/blob/master/itunesReceiptValidator.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved :)

Apparently there is a mechanism for caching receipt in cordova-plugin-purchase that is not needed and actually (was) causing my problems.

So the solution is to call:

```
storekit.setAppStoreReceipt(null);
```

right before fetching the receipt with:

```
storekit.loadReceipts(function (receipts) {
     ...
})
```

that will force plugin to delete cached receipt and always get the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of iTunes receipts:

1. `SKPaymentTransaction#transactionReceipt` (deprecated) and;
2. Apple Grand Unified Receipt, accessed from `appStoreReceiptURL`

You are most likely using the `transactionReceipt` property.

It appears that `cordova-plugin-purchase` implements `appStoreReceiptURL` [here](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/599285e4896bb85cb7744a0abb9eb08422bd2194/src/ios/InAppPurchase.m#L568) and can be accessed from the [IAP.onPurchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/ea8207c8c3976b65196e973ab8d81d96202c65a2/test/src/js/iap.js#L53) method.

Edit:

After looking more closely into the plugin code, there should be a global `storekit` object that exposes a `loadReceipts` method like so

```
storekit.loadReceipts(function (receipts) {
  console.log('Receipt for appStore = ' + receipts.appStoreReceipt);
  console.log('Receipt for ' + productId + ' = ' + receipts.forProduct(productId));
});
```

It's the `receipts.appStoreReceipt` property you will want to send to your server.